# How do I set a watchpoint in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on an issue where a value is changing, but I don't know who/what/where/when it's changing.  Way back the in the day when I was doing C programming in DOS we had "watchpoints" that could be put on a variable to cause a break when it changes.  I'm not finding that in NetBeans (Java application specifically).  What's the comparable method for NetBeans/Java?

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on the line number, you can set a breakpoint.  If you right-click again, you can edit the properties of the breakpoint and set a condition.